# Is Xamarin.Forms stable for a production macOS app?

Tags: ios, macos, xamarin.forms

I can see that it is one of the [platforms](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/wiki/Feature-Roadmap) they support and would like to know if it is stable enough to develop production ready macOS apps.

Comment: Hi, do you mean the [Xamarin Forms Mac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/other/mac) apps? It's a preview feature of Xamarin Forms. I'm not sure whether it's stable, it could support for the most functions of MacOS native app. But there will also be some functions not be supported, actually you know that it is a preview feature now.

Comment: Yes, @JuniorJiang-MSFT, I am thinking of adding a Xamarin.Mac head project to my Xamarin.Forms project and generate a mac build. Also, could you point me towards documents relating to the road map and status of Xamarin.Mac? I noticed that in the Xamarin.Forms github wiki, it is mentioned that it is still in preview. But that was last updated in 2018,

Comment: Hi, you could see my shared link of above comment. That's a official document to guide how to add Mac app for xamarin forms.

Comment: Yes, I looked at it and noticed that the MSDN is last updated in. 2017 and the github doc is last updated in 2018. So, I thought maybe you guys are not updating it anymore. Thank you for clarifying it.

Comment: Okey, maybe the document has not updated recently. However, the source code of [Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Mac](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/tree/5.0.0/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.MacOS) is always being updated.

Answer (score 0):

CollectionView is not supported in Forms 5.0 for macOS.  ListView has problems sizing elements.  It's not ready for production code.